# How to make yAxis column start with value min yAxis in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I use Highcharts to plot the graph, but there is a problem I am facing. data contains the values from 1 to n. So I want the yAxis column to start at 1. I set yAxis min = 1 but it doesn't fix my problem.

Here is a jsfiddle that illustrates the problem I am having:
[Link](https://jsfiddle.net/t4c6nLre/1/)

```
yAxis: {
  title: null,
  endOnTick: false,
  min: 1
}
```

Is there any way to solve my problem? I expect it like this:

[I expect it like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/id0Ss.png)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use `tickPositioner` function and modify the first tick. For example:

```
  yAxis: {
    title: null,
    tickPositioner: function() {
      const tickPositions = [...this.tickPositions];
      tickPositions[0] = 1;
      return tickPositions;
    },
    endOnTick: false,
    startOnTick: false,
    min: 1
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rf3cm8Lw/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositioner

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for ppotaczek answer. I find it pretty cool, can ignore blanks, starting from the smallest element. I have a solution for this and am posting it here for anyone who needs it.

```
  tickPositioner: function () {
        var positions = [],
            tick = Math.floor(this.dataMin),
            increment = Math.ceil((this.dataMax - this.dataMin) / 6);

        if (this.dataMax !== null && this.dataMin !== null) {
            for (tick; tick - increment <= this.dataMax; tick += increment) {
                positions.push(tick);
            }
        }
        return positions;
    }
```